# What are the best materials for an organic skyscraper one kilometer high?

Tags: materials, construction, architecture

The tallest structures on the surface of Earth are trees, which can reach [120-130m already](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15103376/). But I want something much bigger. In the setting of my magic-powered sci-fi story, humans use bioengineered creatures to build organic skyscrapers: the Spires.

Initially, Spires comes as human-sized 'seeds' which, one planted in an appropriate ground, are supplied by pumps with a steady flow of nutrients. The Spires have no branches or leaves, it is mostly a vertical pole supported by strong roots. Spires have multiple hearts to propel the flow of nutrients up to the latest stages, hence overcoming the limitation of our IRL trees.

After its colossal growth over a decade, the Spire is emptied out and human habitations installed within.

Geometry of the Spire would be like a thin cone with its base on the ground. The habitable section is considered as any portion with a width larger than 3 meters. I would like the diameter of Spire's base to be between 50-100 meters.

[image]

**What organic materials would be strong enough to support the growth of the habitable section of such a structure up to a kilometer?**

Answers involving really organic materials/structures, such as wood or mother-of-pearl, would be preferred over the ones with yet-artificial compounds such as carbone nanotubes or graphene.

Comment: Any material can suffice. You could for example take cotton and make a Mt Everest size model of it 9 kms high. The problem is, you need a really large base for the support of such a large weight

Comment: The answer is spiders, or possibly silkworms. Maybe limpet-teeth, or calcium phosphate. You can do it in leather. - Could you narrow the requirements so there's a single best answer as at present this could work with almost anything in a big pile.

Comment: @ArktourosUltorMaximus7600 no matter how wide the base, a pile of material does not constitute a building

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. do you think you could create a 1km tall pile of any random material with a base 100m across?

Comment: The tallest organic skyscraper is the redwood tree at 100m. Good Luck getting to 1km in normal gravity.

Comment: @MS what constitutes a building is the fact that it was, well, built.

Comment: Why do your humans need skyscrapers?

Comment: How is it habitable? Is it hollow?

Comment: I was thinking some carbon-based superstructure held in place by spider silk-based fibers might work as cable suspensions

Comment: your design is unfeasible not due to material but do to the ground. the real problem is the ground under the building 100meters is tiny, if your spire in on anything but solid granite its going to fall over because the ground is not strong enough to hold it up. for scale this is less than HALF as wide as the Burj Khalifa which is almost 200 meters shorter, flares out at the base , and is attached to bedrock. triple the width of the base and it might be possible.

Comment: You would be wise to add "fireproof" to your requirements for the material.

Comment: "Magic-powered  ... bio-engineered ... organic materials" do whatever you want them to in a "magic-powered sci-fi story".

Comment: A better question is, "what kind of properties do I need to bio-engineer into wood so that it can become a single, hollow 1000 meter high spire?"

Comment: Burj Khalifa is already 1km high so perhaps introducing SF skyscrapers is already to wimpy.

Comment: you should should probably start with asking about the best biological building material for a tall sky scraper then after you have selected your material ask about design, because your current design makes in impossible with even current day building materials.

Comment: The question here is why would you want 1 km high skyscrapers. One such building is a bragging right, but having more of them is pointless. High buildings have a logistic issue: https://elevation.fandom.com/wiki/Elevator_conundrum.

Comment: Trees cannot grow beyond 120m because they cannot pump up nutrients any further. The strength of wood is not the limiting factor currently. Wood comes in various strengths and can be bio engineered to be even stronger.

Comment: Thanks all for all your great answers and suggestions. I did not anticipated the problem of foundations, now I am thinking of using a network of root-like structures to support the spire. The spires themselves would be elements of a huge city, so from your suggestions I could also use the interconnections between buildings to build high elements atop a forest of smaller spires. Would be a very dense and interconnected environment, I like it. Silk, bone and nacre reinforced with diamond dust as main materials.

Comment: Your real problem likely isn't growing the structure. All organic materials decompose over time when no longer maintained. Option 1: Once the growth is complete the structure is then maintained by mundane means. This might not fit with the values of your envisioned society. Option 2: The transient nature of the structure is just accepted. This requires moving on from or demolishing old structures. Option 3: It's a living structure (possibly colony) where a part of the living space is sacrificed to the organism maintaining it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Bone

Cortical bone has a compressive strength in excess of [200 MPa](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/bone-strength), while concrete is closer to [20-80 MPa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete#Properties). Of course, trees don't make bone, but since they are bioengineering, perhaps they can make a frankencreature that crosses a tree and some large animals so that it incorporates calcium and other minerals for the high strength.

Wood would have higher compressive strength if there were a biological reason for it. A stupid simple way to get this naturally is to simply attach weights to the tops of trees so that they are always in more compression than an unburdened tree. Of course, it would take many generations for this to result in trees that naturally make stronger wood, but perhaps this tribe has been grooming trees to make "ironwood" over thousands of years. And maybe the even seed the soil around the trees with extra minerals to give them the raw materials they need to incorporate them into their trunks.

Note that you want to always size the weight relative to size of the trunk. So you put small weights on saplings, and you increase the weight as the tree grows. Perhaps you add on another layer of weight each year. There could even be a tradition for this, and this method could be incorporated into the culture that produces these behemoths.

Comment: I really like the idea of using bone! I prefer the spires having a fast growth though, as it would be presented as a major feat of the latests human magitech advances and be implied in the restructuration of their capital city.

Comment: no need for animals just because you want bones. "trees" could construct calcium-based "bones" just as well

Comment: also @CyanadeGhourt on the topic of fast-growing bones, consider an antler-like material (which "grows extremely quickly, [...] as much as 14 kg in 6 months, and at a rate of up to 2–4 cm-day" - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0928493111000701)

Comment: @CyanadeGhourt It's your story. Make the bone grow as fast as you want.

Answer (score 12):

## Red Oakwood, but very unlikely

Although your organic Spire skyscrapers are not impossible, they are very, very hard to create. Red Oak seems a really likely choice, but again, it has its own drawbacks.

According to this [article](https://extension.okstate.edu/fact-sheets/strength-properties-of-wood-for-practical-applications.html#:%7E:text=Some%20of%20the%20mechanical%20properties%20of%20various%20species%20at%2012%20percent%20moisture%20content.%20(From%20Wood%20Handbook%2C%201999)) from Oklahoma University, Red oak has a compressive strength of 6540 PSI, which in MPa, translates to roughly 45 MPa. In case you are new to physics, compressive strength is basically how much load a substance can withstand without breaking apart. Concrete and steel have really high compressive strengths, that's why they are used in building buildings and of course <s>money wasting useless</s> tall skycrapers, that extend to over half a mile (Burj Khalifa) and stuff like that.

45 MPa isn't bad. Granite in contrast has a [compressive strength of over 100-300 MPa](https://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=3d4056a86e79481cb6a80c89caae1d90&ckck=1). Granite is basically the stuff which comprises most of Mt. Everest.[image]

The summit and the topmost part is basically just marine limestone and stuff.

Basically, you can get 1km tall organic skyscrapers, but the problem is, you need a really wide base for the building. I cannot calculate the exact width of a 1km tall red oak skyscraper, but something tells me it would be far in excess of the 50-100m diameter of the base.

TL;DR Although your "organic skyscrapers" are indeed possible, they would be a pain in the a- really hard to make them, considering any organic material crushes down if its very tall, unless it has a wide base.

Note: Spider-silk or silk does NOT SUFFICE. Sure it does have a strong tensile strength, meaning that it is hard to tear apart. But creating a multi-story skyscraper out of silk or SS, would be akin to building a Burj Khalifa out of jelly.

Comment: Wood is very lightweight, so 45MPa means it can carry 4,500 tons per square meter. Which is a theoretical 3km at a density of 1.5 Kg/m3. (Metric makes this so much easier) The stability of the structure would be more of a concern.

Answer (score 6):

I did some reading.

- Concrete tops out at 40Mpa
- Granite tops out at 300MPa
- Hydroxyapatite (enamel) tops out at 400Mpa
- Nacre (Mother of Pearl) exceeds 500Mpa

So in theory a Nacre skyscraper would be very workable. Possibly you'd want some additional internal tethers to balance it for wind shear.

Comment: Where's the source?

Comment: mass is also a factor, being strong does not help of you are also significantly heavier.

Comment: That's a good point, but the density of Granite, Enamel and Nacre all average around 2.7g/cm^3 . Interestingly concrete is 2.4g/cm^3.

Comment: It's MPa (not Mpa). I assume this is compressive strength, but without stating that explicitly these numbers are meaningless

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you could handwave something with cellulose, spiderwebs, and the other materials people have mentioned. Maybe have it grow akin to those somewhat organic looking AI designed structures,[image]  and use that as a justification for it to be relatively much stronger than a regular building of the same material. You could also have people perform 'surgery' on the building at certain points in its growth cycle, adding steel rebar to aid in its strength.

Answer (score 4):

**Use tension and compression for a yurt-style shape**
Surround the high-compression-strength base with an unbroken band of high-tensile strength material.  Perfect graphene is ideal for the bands, but making that at low temperatures and pressures in a biological structure is unlikely.

**Hydrogen (or helium)**
Provide lift to your lightweight structure by filling it with gas.  Helium is naturally produced at a very slow rate by uranium deposits, but can be found in pockets in natural gas chambers.  Let's suppose these Seeds only succeed over natural gas chambers.  This is also a handy source of energy in an oxygenated atmosphere.

**Active pumped water and nutrients**
Trees and plants are able to pump water and nutrients up their stalks easily when they are short due to capillary action and the pressure from the water table.  However, your very tall plants would need another mechanism, such as actively spending energy to pump upward.  Gathering rainwater or dew at high elevation is fine, but it contains no nutrients if the water doesn't come out of the ground.

Comment: Sure! I don't see a problem with humans asphyxiating in helium filled *habitable* rooms.

Comment: Adding lifting elements is smart and would be possible indeed, as magic-powered antigrav system exist in my setting. Not a preferred solution as these systems are consuming energy but may be used in the highest structures.

Answer (score 1):

## Sedimentary Rock

[image]

. . . is an organic substance formed from billions of tiny sea creatures, compacted over millions of years to make a hard and rigid building material. Use that.

Comment: you know there are hundreds of sedimantry rocks, at least a dozen made of shells from chalk to limestone. you should ne more specific.

Comment: @John Limestone.

Answer (score 0):

**Coral reef**

Make a pool, fill it with seawater and let the corals grow. Add and remove some mud in certain points to create some voids. While it grows shape a little bit the walls to let it form arches and vaults.

When one layer has grown put some temporary panels to retain the water on the top of that layer and create another pool to grow the second layer. Like the movable box used for [slip forming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_forming).

After it is grown the inhabitants can improve it limestone is easy to carve. You could have stairs and tunnels built inside the walls, but they will have to be very thick.

Drawback, inhabitants would have to use some kind of cement to plaster the surfaces to prevent weather erosion.

Plot twist: many smaller building where already built in this manner, this tower is special because it is the result of the work of many generations.

Answer (score -3):

In addition to other good answers before me, I'd suggest bio-engineering the tree to include copious amounts of Osmium crystals, a naturally occurring element that is the densest element on Earth. More so than gold, platinum, and diamonds.

That density can make it nearly incompressible. In fact, compressibility is measured in gigapascals (GPa), and diamond rates at 442 GPa, while Osmium rates at 462 GPa, slightly higher.

That in turn makes osmium a great building material, a matrix of osmium in the outermost layer of wood, combined with the designs in previous answers to mine, can provide the outer scaffold for the spire.

Since you are engineering the plant anyway, I'd grow it already hollow: Some variety of giant bamboo seems like the obvious starting point. they are completely hollow, with a very tough outside, and internally (for structural integrity and nutrient transport) are already segmented by periodic "nodes" (the official name), which are analogous to floors in a building.

Combine that with osmium crystals (or microscopic diamond dust), engineer some gigantism, and bingo, you've got a skyscraper.

On Earth, Osmium is much more rare than diamond, but obviously that does not have to be the case for a scifi planet. Maybe their planet got struck billions of years ago with a huge Osmium meteorite shower or something.

And bamboo grows fast, and proliferates fast, so much so it is considered an invasive species that out-competes native vegetation, destroying biodiversity and causing ecological problems, like replacing the food plants and grasses of the local wild animals.

In places where bamboo is native, the wildlife is already adapted to it, and it provides food and shelter, so not considered invasive there.

Overcome the engineering problem of that much height, and bamboo is a great starting point.

Comment: Osmium is a horrible building material because the ground under your building can't support it, so your building falls over.

Comment: Your understanding is completely flawed. Density of a material doesn't affect the compressive strength. In fact, gold which is about 70% as dense as osmium can easily be bent by your fingers.

Comment: @ArktourosUltorMaximus7600 I'm certain you are wrong; the compressibility is measured by the bulk modulus and density is a major factor. There is definitely a correlation. Gold is *not* very compressible; bending is not compression, it doesn't less the volume of the gold. Gold has strong metallic bonding and a face-centered cubic crystalline structure, this makes it not very compressible it all. The bulk modulus of Gold is 170 GPa. The bulk modulus of Water is 2.2 GPa, water is much more compressible than gold. It has nothing to do with bending or flowing. It is about stress based on weight.

Comment: @John That's just silly. the roots support it, they will necessarily be deep and long over a wide area, and ultimately rest on bedrock. Just like all super skyscrapers. It is not difficult to find bedrock close to the surface, or even exposed, right here on Earth.

Comment: @Amadeus So… what happens when your building flows under its own weight? (And why does your answer suggest diamond _dust_ as an alternative?)

Comment: @Amadeus but you can't plant a seed in bedrock, and the roots can't do a 90 degree turn at the surface and spread out for hundreds of meters and still significantly spread out the weight, the entire thing needs to be wide enough or the roots will be just torn off. Also osmium has high compressive strength but just like diamond it relies on a crystal lattice to do so, which makes is very brittle buildings need tension strength too because they will bend under wind load.

Comment: @John I didn't say "plant a seed in bedrock". I said "ultimately rest on bedrock." The roots will grow in soil; but they won't grow through the bedrock, so ultimately, they will grow until they hit bedrock, and the root growth will spread out from there, so the entire tree is ***resting*** on bedrock. It won't ***sink***. The ground doesn't *have* to support it, the *bedrock* will provide the support, and the roots in the soil above the bedrock will provide the nutrients.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 it won't "flow". rock is more compressible than osmium, and mountains can be far heavier and taller, some have peaks well over 5 kilometers above the lowest point between them and neighboring mountains. There won't be any flow, the osmium crystals incorporated into the wood matrix will rest against each other and provide the internal scaffolding that supports the wood. That's the point of the osmium, it forms the "skeleton" of the outer shell. And the tree is not as heavy as it looks; like bamboo, it *grows* hollow, with natural internal floors and ceilings. Like bamboo.

Comment: @Amadeus mountains can be taller because they are also much much wider because the rock in mountains does flow  if you tried to make a mountain shaped like this it would collapse until it is is mountain shaped.

Comment: @Amadeus You seem to think everything's about compressibility. That's not how materials science works. You can't make a 10cm tower out of water; why do you think you can make a 1km tower out of osmium? "Osmium crystals" is passable handwavium, but that's all.

Comment: This answer is wrong in multiple aspects. First of all, Diamond has a bulk modulus of 530 GPa, while osmium has only 470 GPa or something. Second of all, you are confusing density with hardness. Density, although a factor in determining the bulk modulus, does NOT define density. In fact, even though gold, which is more than 2/3rds as dense as osmium is so malleable, if you made a mountain out of gold, it would probably crush itself down and flow outwards. Furthermore Osmium is NOT organic, which is what the OP is asking for, so this answer is invalid in all aspects.

Comment: @ArktourosUltorMaximus7600 Unlike diamond, osmium is not inert but highly reactive, and in fact is usually found in compounds. For a fictional story, which is what the WorldBuilding site is all about, it is scientifically plausible a bio-engineered plant can absorb osmium compounds, alter them and use the osmium for structural purposes. I am looking for an incompressible element that is biologically available, and osmium is the best candidate. You are right, diamond is 530 GPa, I was mistaken, but it is not reactive, where osmium IS. Osmium is still the best choice.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think it is all about compressibility; a 1 km tower cannot deform or break under its own weight. The plant must build an internal structure that supports its weight, even at the ground level. I am unaware of organic materials likely to support that weight, but living things can and do incorporate non-biological elements, and an incompressible metal seems like a good choice to me. What do you think the question, which I will remind is looking for plausible **fiction**, is asking about?

Comment: @Amadeus I know you think that. You are wrong. Compressibility would affect whether the 1km column surrounded by perfectly-rigid unobtanium walls remains 1km tall under load, but that's the extent of its relevance here.